# log regression - what is the last variable in this equation? it wasn't defined can this be the error term?

Tags: regression, econometrics, logarithm

[image]

Can someone help me understand what ∆η_it is?

EDIT: From the comments, the paper is  Hunt, J., & Gauthier-Loiselle, M. (2010). [*How much does immigration boost innovation?*](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/mac.2.2.31)

Comment: Could you provide the source where you found this equation? Have you tried reading a few pagers before?

Comment: It's the regression used in Hunt, J., & Gauthier-Loiselle, M. (2010). How much does immigration boost innovation? yes, but they don't mention it.

Comment: The delta comes from taking time differences of the state levels equation. This is explained above equation (3).

Answer (score 1):

The full paper, for anyone else who wants to look, is [here](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/mac.2.2.31) (the citation is in @Ino's comment; I will put it in the text of the question).

$\Delta \eta_{it}$ certainly *looks* like an error term. First, it's the last term in the formula and that's often the error term. Second, in the formula just above it, they also don't define the (different) error term. I admit I don't rememeber ever seeing the $\Delta$ (for change) in the error term this way, but I am not an econometrician. (I added "econometrics" as a tag, so maybe this will attract their attention).

Comment: +1.  Because this term uses the same indices $(i,t)$ as the response, if it weren't random it would be unidentifiable.  Moreover, in the context of the immediately preceding model (where "$\epsilon$" is explicitly included as an error term), our default interpretation would be that $\eta$ is random error.